# get userinput and display on screen in ajax and php

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

When the user fills value in input box it should display on screen dynamically...
So far, one I created, but facing difficulty in the second one please help out...
One submit button is working but second is not working even alert is not working on click... this is my function in controller

```
function mohsin()
    {
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        echo $message;

        // $message1 = $_POST['message1'];
        // echo $message1;
    }
```

I Dont know where is code not working i follow the same procedure how i did in first one

```js
var counter = 1;
var limit = 4;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]' id='input"+counter+"'><input type='button' value='Submit' id='submit"+counter+"'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}

   $(document).ready(function(){


    $("#submit0").click(function(){
      //alert('hhh');
        $("#input0").hide();
        $("#submit0").hide();
  
          $.ajax({
           "url": "http://localhost/identity/index.php/verify/mohsin",
           "type": "POST",
           data: {message : $("#input0").val()},
           dataType: "text",  
        success :  function (result) {
               $('#demo0').html(result);
        },
    });
  return false;
    });
});


   $("#submit1").click(function(){
      alert('hhh');
        $("#input1").hide();
        $("#submit1").hide();
  
          $.ajax({
           "url": "http://localhost/identity/index.php/verify/mohsin",
           "type": "POST",
           data: {message : $("#input1").val()},
           dataType: "text",  
        success :  function (result) {
               $('#demo1').html(result);
        },
    });
  return false;
    });
    
    <?php
    function mohsin()
  {
   $message = $_POST['message'];
   echo $message;

   // $message1 = $_POST['message1'];
   // echo $message1;
  }
    ?>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form method="POST">
     <div id="dynamicInput">
          <!-- Entry 1 --><br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]" id="input0">
          <input type="button" name="" value="Submit" id="submit0">
     </div>
     <p id="demo0"></p>
     <p id="demo1"></p>
     <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
</form>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your second event to following:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit1', function(){
  alert('hhh');
  $("#input1").hide();
  $("#submit1").hide();
  $.ajax({
      "url": "http://localhost/identity/index.php/verify/mohsin",
      "type": "POST",
       data: {message : $("#input1").val()},
       dataType: "text",  
       success :  function (result) {
         $('#demo1').html(result);
       },
   });
   return false;
});
```

But you still have a issue in your code, because you are incrementing the value `counter`. So when your counter  will set to 2 then it will not found the id `value2` on dom.

Lets update your code to following to work it properly :

Your Html :

```
<form method="POST">
  <div id="dynamicInput">
    <br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]" id="input0">
    <input type="button" name="" value="Submit" id="submit0">
  </div>
  <p id="results"></p>
  <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
</form>
```

Javascript :

```
function addInput(divName){
    if (counter == limit)  {
      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
    }
    else {
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]' id='input"+counter+"'><input type='button' onclick='addValue("+counter+")' value='Submit' id='submit"+counter+"'>";
      document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
      counter++;
    }
  }


function addValue(counter) {
    alert('hhh');
    $("#input"+counter).hide();
    $("#submit"+counter).hide();
    $.ajax({
      "url": "c.php",
      "type": "POST",
      data: {message : $("#input"+counter).val()},
      dataType: "text",  
      success :  function (result) {
          $('#results').append(result);
      },
    });
    return false;
  }
```

And update your php file to:

```
<?php 
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  echo '<p>'.$message.'</p>';
?>
```

Comment: @mohsinshaikh check the updated code for properly working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your

> $("#submit1").click(function(){

is out of bind to future element. So the click function is not bind till now.
You can do couple of things 
first bind function with future element (which is your case). You need to use `live` or `on` both will work. Second thing is you are using it so if the id is change it will not work anymore. Better use class for here.